# Export Java project as JAR with ressources out of it

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I currently have a basic Java project, that I want to deliver as an executable JAR. The program within it is based on several resource files, which must be editable by the user, or by a third-party program, which means that those files must not be embedded into the JAR archive.

I am using Eclipse to develop my project. The question is :

How to make the exportation of those files automatic, to end up with the JAR, and right next to it, a folder containing the resources for exemple (if that is possible of course) ?

Every thing I've tried or found on the net concerns resources delivered within the JAR, which avoids any modification of those resources. The ideal solution would copy the files right next to the JAR when it is exported.

Comment: By 'files' do you mean .properties files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse's "export executable JAR" functionality can't do this directly, it's limited to the contents of the JAR. I recommend you investigate doing this with a build tool like Gradle, Maven, or Ant, and then invoking that from Eclipse or via command-line.